# function and output foreach result with html

Tags: php, mysqli

My problem is for output $items on div.link,all test is not good because the first test display result on body and second test dispay result in top body not in my specific div

First bad test:

```
function list($id) {

        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `social` WHERE `userid` = '%s'", $id);

        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        $table = array();

        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                $table[] = $row['username'];

            }

            echo '<div class="sidebar friends">';
                    echo '<div class="content">';
                    echo     '<div class="head">Group</div>';
                    echo       '<div class="inner">';

                    foreach($table as $items){
                        echo '<div class="link">';
                        echo $items;
                        echo'</div>';
                        }   

                            echo'</div>';
                        echo'</div>';
                echo'</div>';

        } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

better result is like this, but output is not in my div link because before i closing variable output:

```
function list($id) {

    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `social` WHERE `userid` = '%s'", $id);

    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    $table = array();

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $table[] = $row['username'];

        }

    $output =  '<div class="sidebar friends"> 
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="head">Group</div>
                            <div class="inner">
                                <div class="link">'; //i closing var but foreach result not displayed in div link
                                //how i can output result here in div link?
                            foreach($table as $items){
                                echo $items; //items need to be display...
                            }
                $output .=  '</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';

        return $output;
        } else {
            return false;

    }
}
```

how i can using foreach for output result in my div.link?

here is how i need to display:

```
<div class="sidebar-container widget-welcome"> 
    <div class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="sidebar-header">Group</div>
            <div class="sidebar-inner">
                <div class="sidebar-link">

                    //foreach output items result here

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want to display the output? Can you show the expected HTML output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wont show up because you are ECHO'ing `$item`. The fix is to append the $item with the `$output` string you are returning from the function.

Please change your loop like below:

```
foreach($table as $items){
            $output .= $items; //items need to be display...
     }
```

Comment: Omg, i have FAIL ;( a small detail that can kill you.. thanks you for help! it's solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Change your block of code as below ( place your `link` div inside loop and append closing div properly)

```
$output =  '<div class="sidebar friends"> 
            <div class="content">
            <div class="head">Group</div>
            <div class="inner">';
                foreach($table as $items){
                        $output .= '<div class="link">'.$items.'</div>';
                }
$output .='</div></div></div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

ON a different note, I'd recommend simply moving the html to a different file and then including it, Passing $table as a parameter and looping there. increases readability quite a bit.